# What is the correct way to rename an aspx page without causing reference problems?

Tags: asp.net

If I renamed my aspx page in VS2012 manually, some references to the page aren't renamed like the class name within the .cs page, the designer class and the aspx "inherits" class.
Is there a way to rename my page to replace all the references to the old name with the new name ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Visual Studio is pretty limited in regards to renaming controls, and there isn't a built in function that can change all references in many cases.

The best option is to look at tools such as [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which allow for better re-factoring.